# How do I turn a managed metadata value into a link that displays all pages which also have that value?

Tags: 2013, metadata, links

I have a control which displays a list of all managed metadata tags which has been associated with the current page.

I want to turn these tag values into links which when clicked will load a page containing links to all pages which have that value in their managed metadata field.